# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): SELECT command denied to user 'XXX'@'YYY' for table 'bogus_table'

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I'm using Dapper for calling MySql stored procedure. The procedure executes just fine, but after that the code throws an exception. The code block that is problematic is like this:

```
    using (var conn = DataFactory.InitializeConnection(false))
    {
        conn.Query("ProcedureName", new
        {
            puserid = ID
        }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
```

Where `DataFactory` is the following static class:

```
public static class DataFactory
{
    public static IDbConnection InitializeConnection(bool open = true, string connectionstring = "", string databaseServerType = "MYSQL")
    {
        if (string.Equals(databaseServerType, "MYSQL"))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionstring))
                connectionstring = Settings.Default.DataConnectionString;
            var csb = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionstring);
            var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
            Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;

            if (open)
                conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented for your database provider");
    }
}
```

I have no `bogus_table` in my database, tho it is shown in the error message:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): SELECT command
>   denied to user 'XXX'@'YYY' for table **'bogus_table'**    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int64& insertedId)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ClearKillFlag()
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Dispose()    at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.d__136`1.<>m__Finally1()    at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__136`1.MoveNext()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's maybe problem in  [Mysql Driver](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/68c54371821c87ff40a773acc127ce357b46a5ae/Source/MySql.Data/datareader.cs) implementation; here is code block that mentions [bogus_table](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bogus_table%20&type=).
if your procedure has empty result try to call with Execute *(because it implements execute non query inside)*  instead of Query.

```
using (var conn = DataFactory.InitializeConnection(false))
    {
        conn.Execute("ProcedureName", new
        {
            puserid = ID
        }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered, kind of like same issue with 'bogus_table' which indeed comes from MySql code!

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Table 'myspector.bogus_table' doesn't exist'
```

You are maybe in debug mode with **all** exceptions enabled.
When this exception raises, uncheck *'break when this exception is thrown'* like in the image below:

[image: bogus table screen]

Then, restart / continue, and you will see that this exception and is  **catched by another exception handler in the stack** : it is **transformed** into a classic *InvalidOperationException*:

```
    {"Sequence contains no elements"}   System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, but we had a problem on production release build. The answer marked solution helped in our case.